# Fit points to a Lorentzian curve and find center and half maximum bandwidth in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I am using a python program to pull discreet values from a network analyzer. It pulls 401 y-axis values and calculates the corresponding x-axis values, and I wish to fit them to a lorentzian curve and find the x-axis value of the y-axis maximum and the half y-axis maximum width.
The lorentzian function I wish to fit these points to is

```
(1/pi)(a/((x-x0)^2+(a)^2))
```

and I must find `a` and `x0` given the `x` and `y` values returned from the network analyzer. Is there a simple way to do this using `scipy` or `numpy`? I usually try and post any attempt I have made, but I'm not sure where to even start. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Zhenya I would suggest using [curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html). If `xdata` and `ydata` are your values you can do

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def lorentzian(x, a, x0):
    return a / ((x-x0)**2 + a**2) / np.pi

# Obtain xdata and ydata
...

# Initial guess of the parameters (you must find them some way!)
pguess = [a_guess, x0_guess]

# Fit the data
popt, pcov = curve_fit(lorentzian, xdata, ydata, p0 = pguess)

# Results
a, x0 = popt[0], popt[1]
```

A suggestion to make the initial guess could be:

```
a_guess = 1 / (np.pi * max(ydata))
x0_guess = sum(xdata * ydata) / sum(ydata)
```

I have not tested the code, but in principle it should work.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I have not tried it yet either, but my main confusion was with the initial guess and now I understand thanks to your code.

Answer (score 0):

For a basic example of fitting, see e.g. http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/FittingData.

There are multiple examples here on SO on how to use a (more modern) `curve_fit` from scipy.optimize.

For a lorenzian, I'd

- fit in the log space
- use the maximum of the data for the starting guess for `x0`